# Can't connect by SSH after using SCP to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, scp

My actions on server:

1. Create EC2 instance on AWS
2. Successfully connect by SSH to it using
   key `ssh -i "lala.pem"ubuntu@ec7-77-777-77-777.compute-1.amazonaws.com`
3. Install LEMP
4. Upload an archive to the server `scp C:\blabla\master.zip -i "lala.pem" ubuntu@ec7-77-777-77-777.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/var/www` without error
5. After SCP command using I can't connect to the server back by SSH due to timeout error

   `teddy:.ssh mike$ ssh -i "lala.pem" ubuntu@ec2-34-238-82-190.compute-1.amazonaws.com -v
   OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
   debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
   debug1: Connecting to ec2-34-238-82-190.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22.
   ssh: connect to host ec2-34-238-82-190.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out`

The server works. I can make a request to it and get a response. I can ping it by IP `ping 77.77.77.77`. I checked Security Groups. I tried to reboot the instance...  but I can't connect by SSH.

What happened?
How can I fix SSH?

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the reason. It was a firewall on ubuntu (`ufw`). When I installed Nginx, using a guide from Digital Ocean, I enabled `ufw` for the server. But in the output of `sudo ufw status` there is not `OpenSSH Allow`.

The right output looks like this:

```
Output
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

But in my case the output looks like:

```
Output
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----         
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere                 
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```